# python static variable in instance method

Tags: python, class, variables, static

Here is my code not working

```
class MyClass:
    special_items = {}
    def preload_items(self):
        special_items['id'] = "properties"
```

NameError: global name 'special_items' is not defined

works

```
class MyClass:
    special_items = {}
    def preload_items(self):
        MyClass.special_items['id'] = "properties"
```

Isn't it `special_items`  a static member I can access anywhere in this class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as static members in python.  What you defined is a class-member.  The member is stored on the class object, and as you already showed, it is accessed as `MyClass.special_items`.

It seems that what you're trying to do is to initialize `special_items.`  For that, `classmethod` is more appropriate (there's no use for `self`):

```
@classmethod
def preload_items(cls):
        cls.special_items['id'] = "properties"
```

Note that you can also access it as `self.special_items`, but it is still stored on the class object, i.e. all objects of the class access the same value.

Comment: Maybe suggest a classmethod for this one ... (or note that `self.special_items['id']` will also work out for this simple example)

Comment: So I have to attach something before this special_items? No  a clean way to call this variable in python?

Comment: Why do you consider it not clean?  You can define a global variable, but if the variable is logically-associated with MyClass, class member is way better.

Comment: @wwli: Perhaps it would be helpful to specify the language in which a "clean way" is used, and explain what specifically about that "clean way" you prefer over Python's semantics.

Comment: @bernie from c++ and java apparently you can access such a static/class variable with nothing attached :)

Comment: @wwli: And is that more clear? Looking at it from the other point of view, could it perhaps be a less clean way or a potential source of confusion?

Comment: @bernie well inside a class it is quite clear and clean, at least to me :)

Comment: @wwli, you should also consider the "clean" ways to access it in case there's a subclass defining its own `special_items`.  How do you access subclass's `special_items`? How do you access superclass's `special_items`?